# Oracle query: how can I elimitate multiple results from this query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables:

```
CLIENT
 - ID
 - NAME
 - USER

ORDER
 - ID
 - DATE
 - CLIENT_ID
 - USER

ORDER_LINE
 - ORDER_ID
 - LINE_ID
 - USER
```

The user field tracks the person who last modified the record. Additionally, each line item may be modified by a different user.

I'm trying to find out, given a USER, what orders they have been involved with.

```
select 
 client.id,
 client.name,
 order.id,
 order.date,
 case
   when order_line.user = :user then 'Line Item'
   when order.user = :user then 'Order'
   when client.user = :user then 'Client'
 end
from
 order_line
 join order on order_id = order.id
 join client on order.client_id = client.id
where
 order_line.user = :user
 or order.user = :user
 or client.user = :user
```

The problem is that a user may touch both the order and order_line tables, so I get multiple results.  Adding select distinct doesn't help, since the result of the case statement is different in each case.

Is there a way to restructure the query so I only get one result per order?

The result of the case statement isn't really that important - it would be nice if I could get "Line Item, Order" in the case of someone touching both tables but just "Line Item" would be OK.

Comment: So the case statement is not important? Or how would you choose between different cases when you oly want one line per order?

Comment: @cularis: I updated the question with a clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this

It will show all orders that the user altered and if he altered line items but not what line items

```
SELECT   client.id,
         client.name,
         order.id,
         order.date
  FROM      order
         JOIN
            client
         ON client_id = client.id
 WHERE      order.USER = :USER
         OR client.USER = :USER
         OR :USER IN (SELECT   USER
                       FROM   ORDER_LINE OL
                      WHERE   ORDER_LINE.ORDER_ID = ORDER.ID)
```

Comment: That seems to be the easiest, and I can add a case statement in there too.

Answer (score 0):

does oracle have group_concat (or similar) as mysql has?

```
select client_id, name, order_id, date, group_concat(what separator ', ') as changes
from (
select 
 client.id as client_id,
 client.name,
 order.id as order_id,
 order.date,
 case
   when order_line.user = :user then 'Line Item'
   when order.user = :user then 'Order'
   when client.user = :user then 'Client'
 end as what
from
 order_line
 join order on order_id = order.id
 join client on order.client_id = client.id
where
 order_line.user = :user
 or order.user = :user
 or client.user = :user
) as part1
group by client_id, name, order_id, date;
```

Comment: There appears to be something similar, but I'm not familiar enough with these types of structures to understand what's going on: http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/08/evolution.html

Comment: I also found (depending on the oracle version) LISTAGG and WM_CONCAT as direct replacement of group_concat (the last not documented by oracle). [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) is a brief of this two and other techniques

Answer (score 0):

How about concatenating the last column and using distinct, something like this:

```
select distinct
 client.id,
 client.name,
 order.id,
 order.date,
 case when order_line.user = :user then 'Line Item ' else '' end ||
  case when order.user = :user then 'Order ' else '' end ||
  case when client.user = :user then 'Client ' else '' end
from
 order_line
 join order on order_id = order.id
 join client on order.client_id = client.id
where
 order_line.user = :user
 or order.user = :user
 or client.user = :user
```

?

Comment: I still end up with 2 results: one with just 'Order', one with 'Line Item Order'

Comment: Hmm - I think you might want to add user to the joins, like: `from
 order_line
 join order on order_id = order.id and order_line.user=order.user
 join client on order.client_id = client.id and order.user=client.user`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
select client_id,
       max(client_name),
       order_id,
       max(order_date),
       max(Line_User),
       max(Order_User),
       max(Client_User)
(select client.id client_id,
        client.name client_name,
        order.id order_id,
        order.date order_date,
        case when order_line.user = :user then 'Y' else 'N' end Line_User,
        case when order.user = :user then 'Y' else 'N' end Order_User,
        case when client.user = :user then 'Y' else 'N' end Client_User
 from order_line
 join order on order_id = order.id
 join client on order.client_id = client.id
 where order_line.user = :user or order.user = :user or client.user = :user)
group by client_id, order_id;
```